# Error con certificado al cambiar configuración del Balanceador

Tags: java, spring, ssl, certificado-ssl

Estoy teniendo problemas con una aplicación java que se comunica con un Web Service.

Inicialmente el nombre de red, integracion.comunicaciones, sólo resolvía una IP. Usando el certificado en dos máquinas distintas a través del `keystore`, funcionaba correctamente.
Recientemente, se ha añadido una segunda IP y cuando integracion.comunicaciones me devuelve la segunda IP, la aplicación me devuelve el siguiente error de certificado.

> ***javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:  PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target***

Revisando el certificado veo que está validado integracion.comunicaciones, pero me da a pensar que por debajo, sólo está validando la primera IP. ¿Es posible que este sea el fallo? ¿Influye la IP que se resuelva en la creación del certificado?

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que tendrias que agregar las dos ips en el archivo de hosts del ordenador e indicarles que el dominio "integracion.comunicaciones" puede resolver la ip1 y la ip2.

En Windows C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts modifica este archivo,en linux es el mismo archivo pero con diferencia en la ubicación.
al final del archivo escribir las siguientes líneas ,no anteponer "#" porque se tomara como un comentario.

190.128.0.1                integracion.comunicaciones

190.128.0.2                integracion.comunicaciones

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se solventó generando un certificado para cada IP asociada, que aunque no lo pudiese ver en el original, no se contemplaba la segunda IP.